# Passing Parameters into Android Volley POST Request, return JSON

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am attempting a Volley POST request that passes in the parameter `friends_phone_number_csv` that should then return a JSON object. However in using the request below it simply notes:

```
 E/Volley﹕ [4230] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://(ip-address):3000/getActivatedFriends.json
```

In testing this request in chromes POSTMAN I know the webservice is correct and should return a JSON object.

How can I make this work?

The POST request in app:

```
JsonObjectRequest getUserActiveFriends = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://" + Global.getFeastOnline() + "/getActivatedFriends.json",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // Parse the JSON:
                        try {
                            resultObject = response.getJSONObject("friends_match");

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // PARSE THE REST

                            //Log.v("USER ID", "The user id is " + userId);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("friends_phone_number_csv", contactsNumbers);

                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(getUserActiveFriends);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code, when you post request and return json data, you should add content type "application/json; charset=utf-8" to http header.

```
 @Override
 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();                   
   headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
   return headers;
 }
```